# Android - Start new Activity without pausing the current

Tags: android

Suppose current Activity called "A1" is running.
I want to start Activity "A2", but do not pause(call onPause()) and then resume "A1" when returning with back button.
Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: Can you explain the reason why you need this? So that someone can help you with a good solution for it.

Comment: what are you trying to achieve by doing that? just wondering

Comment: I'm using libGDX framework. A1 is gameplay activity which is doing huge work when resumeing. A2 is a simple Android PreferenceActivity. When I return  from A2 to A1 it lasts for 3 seconds to resume the game.

Comment: i think you must read this link - http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#ActivityLifecycle. you will be able to understand the flow of the activity

Comment: when u r navigating from one activity to another onPause will be called and when returning to it onresume will be called

Comment: You can add this preference thing in your current activity itself and when user opens it, you can just change its visibility and show it on top of your current view. This way you wont be pausing your current activity.

Comment: Use a dialog to show the "preferences"

Comment: @mudit I have thought about it. But I want to use PreferenceActivity because it mekes creating Settings of game really fast and easy.

Answer (score 5):

What you're trying to achieve is not feasible. However, Android 3.0 has introduced the concept of `Fragments`. `Fragment` roughly speaking is a part of `Activity` layout with its own logic. By combining different `Fragments` you can create a multipart layout which will look like you have more than one `Activity` running at the same. `Fragments` are also supported in Android versions lower than 3.0 if using the Support Library. You can take advantage of `Fragments` concept in your application as it looks like this is the case. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, I know about Fragments. But I need to run my app on 2.2.

Comment: @narek.gevorgyan, Probably you've not read my answer properly, cause I've said that Fragments can be used from Android 1.6 and up, thanks to the Support Library.